# Scala Partition/Collect Usage

Tags: list, scala, collect

Is it possible to use one call to `collect` to make 2 new lists? If not, how can I do this using `partition`?

Answer (score 83, accepted):

`collect` (defined on [TraversableLike](http://www.scala-lang.org/archives/downloads/distrib/files/nightly/docs/library/scala/collection/TraversableLike.html) and available in all subclasses) works with a collection and a `PartialFunction`.  It also just so happens that a bunch of case clauses defined inside braces are a partial function (See section 8.5 of the [Scala Language Specification](http://www.scala-lang.org/sites/default/files/linuxsoft_archives/docu/files/ScalaReference.pdf) *[warning - PDF]*)

As in exception handling:

```
try {
  ... do something risky ...
} catch {
  //The contents of this catch block are a partial function
  case e: IOException => ...
  case e: OtherException => ...
}
```

It's a handy way to define a function that will only accept some values of a given type.

Consider using it on a list of mixed values:

```
val mixedList = List("a", 1, 2, "b", 19, 42.0) //this is a List[Any]
val results = mixedList collect {
  case s: String => "String:" + s
  case i: Int => "Int:" + i.toString
}
```

The argument to to `collect` method is a `PartialFunction[Any,String]`.  `PartialFunction` because it's not defined for all possible inputs of type `Any` (that being the type of the `List`) and `String` because that's what all the clauses return.

If you tried to use `map` instead of `collect`, the the double value at the end of `mixedList` would cause a `MatchError`.  Using `collect` just discards this, as well as any other value for which the PartialFunction is not defined.

One possible use would be to apply different logic to elements of the list:

```
var strings = List.empty[String]
var ints = List.empty[Int]
mixedList collect {
  case s: String => strings :+= s
  case i: Int => ints :+= i
}
```

Although this is just an example, using mutable variables like this is considered by many to be a war crime - So please don't do it!

A *much* better solution is to use collect twice:

```
val strings = mixedList collect { case s: String => s }
val ints = mixedList collect { case i: Int => i }
```

Or if you know for certain that the list only contains two types of values, you can use `partition`, which splits a collections into values depending on whether or not they match some predicate:

```
//if the list only contains Strings and Ints:
val (strings, ints) = mixedList partition { case s: String => true; case _ => false }
```

The catch here is that both `strings` and `ints` are of type `List[Any]`, though you can easily coerce them back to something more typesafe (perhaps by using `collect`...)

If you already have a type-safe collection and want to split on some other property of the elements, then things are a bit easier for you:

```
val intList = List(2,7,9,1,6,5,8,2,4,6,2,9,8)
val (big,small) = intList partition (_ > 5)
//big and small are both now List[Int]s
```

Hope that sums up how the two methods can help you out here!

Comment: Very nice explanation, but what I think OP wants is a combination of `collect` and `partition` that returns a tuple of a list of the collected values and a list of all the rest. `def collectAndPartition[A, B](pf: PartialFunction[A, B]): (List[B], List[A])`. This would probably be most elegantly achieved with a native library function, i.e. in the source of `collect` in TraversableLike we have `for (x <- this) if (pf.isDefinedAt(x)) b += pf(x)`, one could simply tack an `else a += x` at the end of that, where `a` would be a builder for the list of all the rest.

Comment: I know what the OP needs, and I'm also aware that this is a homework question (it's been mentioned on stack overflow a lot recently), so I'll gladly give plenty of theory without actually solving it. As for collectAndPartition, I already wrote that, though I named the method `collate`. If anyone is teaching scala to the level where students are expected to work with CanBuildFrom then I'll be very surprised, it's beyond most people currently using scala in production.

Comment: That was very helpful. But I'm still thinking... is it possible to separate for example positive and negative values, without making a "war crime" as you wrote erlier? I'm just courious becouse I've allready done homework with using partition. Ohhh... And by the way, Thanks for help!

Comment: `collect`, like `map`, takes one collection and converts it to another collection. It can certainly help in processing data and making it easier to separate in a following operation, but there's no way to generate two collections using just `collect` unless you rely on side effects (i.e. mutable variables). This sort of hack leads to code that's harder to read, and is best left for times when there's no other alternative or it gives a vital performance boost, neither of which applies here.

Comment: there is a nice example in [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14703971/618089) that shows how to use collect to split a stream.

Comment: One could also use groupBy to define some criteria for splitting to N number of sublists, and then take required groups by their keys. For example in this case key could be surrogate enum or java class instance, or boolean and then you're back with quite same result as partition provides

Answer (score 7):

Not sure how to do it with `collect` without using mutable lists, but `partition` can use pattern matching as well (just a little more verbose)

```
List("a", 1, 2, "b", 19).partition { 
  case s:String => true
  case _ => false 
}
```

Comment: @coubeatczech - Because partition returns a `(List[A],List[A])`.  That's all it can do since the input is a `List[A]` and an indicator function `A => Boolean`.  It has no way of knowing that the indicator function might be type-specific.

Comment: @Rex I defined my own `collate` method to pimp onto collections that solves just this problem.  On a `List[A]` the use-case signature is `collate[B](fn: PartialFunction[A,B]): (List(B),List(A))`, obviously the *actual* signature is a bit hairier than that as I'm also using `CanBuildFrom`

Answer (score 6):

The signature of the normally-used `collect` on, say, `Seq`, is

```
collect[B](pf: PartialFunction[A,B]): Seq[B]
```

which is really a particular case of

```
collect[B, That](pf: PartialFunction[A,B])(
  implicit bf: CanBuildFrom[Seq[A], B, That]
): That
```

So if you use it in default mode, the answer is no, assuredly not: you get exactly one sequence out from it.  If you follow `CanBuildFrom` through `Builder`, you see that it would be possible to make `That` actually be two sequences, but it would have no way of being told which sequence an item should go into, since the partial function can only say "yes, I belong" or "no, I do not belong".

So what do you do if you want to have multiple conditions that result in your list being split into a bunch of different pieces?  One way is to create an indicator function `A => Int`, where your `A` is mapped into a numbered class, and then use `groupBy`.  For example:

```
def optionClass(a: Any) = a match {
  case None => 0
  case Some(x) => 1
  case _ => 2
}
scala> List(None,3,Some(2),5,None).groupBy(optionClass)
res11: scala.collection.immutable.Map[Int,List[Any]] = 
  Map((2,List(3, 5)), (1,List(Some(2))), (0,List(None, None)))
```

Now you can look up your sub-lists by class (0, 1, and 2 in this case).  Unfortunately, if you want to ignore some inputs, you still have to put them in a class (e.g. you probably don't care about the multiple copies of `None` in this case).

Answer (score 5):

I use this. One nice thing about it is it combines partitioning and mapping in one iteration.  One drawback is that it does allocate a bunch of temporary objects (the `Either.Left` and `Either.Right` instances)

```
/**
 * Splits the input list into a list of B's and a list of C's, depending on which type of value the mapper function returns.
 */
def mapSplit[A,B,C](in: List[A])(mapper: (A) => Either[B,C]): (List[B], List[C]) = {
  @tailrec
  def mapSplit0(in: List[A], bs: List[B], cs: List[C]): (List[B], List[C]) = {
    in match {
      case a :: as =>
        mapper(a) match {
          case Left(b)  => mapSplit0(as, b :: bs, cs     )
          case Right(c) => mapSplit0(as, bs,      c :: cs)
        }
      case Nil =>
        (bs.reverse, cs.reverse)
    }
  }

  mapSplit0(in, Nil, Nil)
}

val got = mapSplit(List(1,2,3,4,5)) {
  case x if x % 2 == 0 => Left(x)
  case y               => Right(y.toString * y)
}

assertEquals((List(2,4),List("1","333","55555")), got)
```

Answer (score 5):

Starting in `Scala 2.13`, most collections are now provided with a [`partitionMap`](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.13.x/scala/collection/immutable/List.html#partitionMap%5BA1,A2%5D(f:A=%3EEither%5BA1,A2%5D):(CC%5BA1%5D,CC%5BA2%5D)) method which partitions elements based on a function which returns either `Right` or `Left`.

That allows us to pattern match based on the type (which as a `collect` enables having specific types in the partitioned lists) or any other pattern:

```
val (strings, ints) =
  List("a", 1, 2, "b", 19).partitionMap {
    case s: String => Left(s)
    case x: Int    => Right(x)
  }
// strings: List[String] = List("a", "b")
// ints: List[Int] = List(1, 2, 19)
```

Answer (score 1):

I could not find a satisfying solution to this basic problem here.
I don't need a lecture on `collect` and don't care if this is someone's homework. Also, I don't want something that works only for `List`.

So here is my stab at it. Efficient and compatible with any `TraversableOnce`, even strings:

```
implicit class TraversableOnceHelper[A,Repr](private val repr: Repr)(implicit isTrav: Repr => TraversableOnce[A]) {

  def collectPartition[B,Left](pf: PartialFunction[A, B])
  (implicit bfLeft: CanBuildFrom[Repr, B, Left], bfRight: CanBuildFrom[Repr, A, Repr]): (Left, Repr) = {
    val left = bfLeft(repr)
    val right = bfRight(repr)
    val it = repr.toIterator
    while (it.hasNext) {
      val next = it.next
      if (!pf.runWith(left += _)(next)) right += next
    }
    left.result -> right.result
  }

  def mapSplit[B,C,Left,Right](f: A => Either[B,C])
  (implicit bfLeft: CanBuildFrom[Repr, B, Left], bfRight: CanBuildFrom[Repr, C, Right]): (Left, Right) = {
    val left = bfLeft(repr)
    val right = bfRight(repr)
    val it = repr.toIterator
    while (it.hasNext) {
      f(it.next) match {
        case Left(next) => left += next
        case Right(next) => right += next
      }
    }
    left.result -> right.result
  }
}
```

Example usages:

```
val (syms, ints) =
  Seq(Left('ok), Right(42), Right(666), Left('ko), Right(-1)) mapSplit identity

val ctx = Map('a -> 1, 'b -> 2) map {case(n,v) => n->(n,v)}
val (bound, unbound) = Vector('a, 'a, 'c, 'b) collectPartition ctx
println(bound: Vector[(Symbol, Int)], unbound: Vector[Symbol])
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this could help

```
def partitionMap[IN, A, B](seq: Seq[IN])(function: IN => Either[A, B]): (Seq[A], Seq[B]) = {
  val (eitherLeft, eitherRight) = seq.map(function).partition(_.isLeft)
  eitherLeft.map(_.left.get) -> eitherRight.map(_.right.get)
}
```

To call it

```
val seq: Seq[Any] = Seq(1, "A", 2, "B")
val (ints, strings) = CollectionUtils.partitionMap(seq) {
  case int: Int    => Left(int)
  case str: String => Right(str)
}
ints shouldBe Seq(1, 2)
strings shouldBe Seq("A", "B")
```

Advantage is a simple API, similar with the one from Scala 2.12

Disadvantage; collection is ran twice and missing support for `CanBuildFrom`

Answer (score 0):

I would personally use a foldLeft or foldRight for this.  It has a couple advantages over the some of the other answers here.  No use of var, so this is a pure function (if you care about that type of thing).  Only one traversal through the list.  Does not create any extraneous Either objects.

The idea of a fold is to convert a list into a single type.  However, nothing is stopping us from having this single type be a Tuple of any number of lists.

This example converts a list into three different lists:

```
  val list: List[Any] = List(1,"two", 3, "four", 5.5)

  // Start with 3 empty lists and prepend to them each time we find a new value
  list.foldRight( (List.empty[Int]), List.empty[String], List.empty[Double]) {
    (nextItem, newCollection) => {
      nextItem match {
        case i: Int => newCollection.copy(_1 = i :: newCollection._1)
        case s: String => newCollection.copy(_2 = s :: newCollection._2)
        case f: Double => newCollection.copy(_3 = f :: newCollection._3)
        case _ => newCollection
      }
    }
  }
```